# Name in English of different parts and tools

Tags: parts, tools

What is the name in English of the part that has a set of dented wheels and goes attached to the center of the back wheel of a bicycle?

[image]

What would be the name(s) in English of the tool that allows to remove these dented wheels so that I can replace a broken spoke?

I have had bicycles all my life, but now that I left my country of origin buying tools and parts using a language that is not my mother tongue is a bit challenging sometimes.

(If anyone can provide the same names in French that would be even better).

Comment: [Sheldon](http://sheldonbrown.com/eng-fren.html) has a French-English dictionary page for a bunch of cycling parts/terms. Including cassettes (cassettes) and freehubs (moyeu-roues libres). Any use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have a [terminology index](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index) here that should help you with the more common names. Please feel free to suggest anything that is missing (we do try to keep adding things that are missing)

Unfortunately it doesn't currently have the things you're asking about. The part you've shown is a freewheel, and the tool is called a [freewheel remover](http://www.parktool.com/product/freewheel-remover-fr-1-2). <strike>You also need a [chain whip](http://www.parktool.com/product/sprocket-remover-chain-whip-sr-1) to hold it in place while using that tool.</strike> (edit: no you don't). Note that there are several different types of freewheel removal tools because there are different types of freewheels. See [this blog post](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cassette-and-freewheel-removal), for example.

[image: freewheel remover]

Also, modern bikes tend to use cassettes rather than freewheels. The difference is explained [here by Sheldon Brown](http://sheldonbrown.com/free-k7.html) and here's a picture from his site showing the important bits:

[image: freewhel vs cassette]

Comment: Note that there is a significant difference between a freewheel and a cassette freehub system.

Comment: The dented wheels are called sprockets, and the set of them is also called a cluster; the tool to remove it is also called a cluster remover.

Comment: ... mass editing of the [Terminology Index](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index) will now ensue :)

Comment: @Batman: good point. I hope the picture is accurate. Should I add a "how to tell the difference" picture pair?

Comment: I think it would make it better - most quality bicycles have had cassettes rather than freewheels for a while, so its probably good to note.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a modern bicycle, it's a cassette in English. And the tools are a chain whip and a lockout ring remover or cassette remover.

With [Chain Reaction](http://www.chainreactioncycles) and [Wiggle](http://www.wiggle.co.uk) it is possible to choose French for the language, even if you are in England (I do the opposite in France ;-) )